# FirefoxOS - get resource files from JS?

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

Is there a way to hold a large block of text, or images/videos, embedded in a FirefoxOS app, while directly accessing them from the app (similar to /res/raw/ in Android)? I don't see where the /data/ directory is being accessed in the example app.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that you can do this:

1. Distribute your web app as a [packaged app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps). In this scenario all your resource files are zipped up in a single file, available after install via a URL scheme described in the documentation.
2. The [Application Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) allows you to instruct the browser to download files for offline use. I like [Rob Hawkes' utility](https://appcache-generator.herokuapp.com/) for generating appcache manifest files.
3. You can manage the data yourself by downloading the files via [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and storing the data in an [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) database or on the SD card via the [DeviceStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Storage_API).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet is the [filehandle API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_Handle_API), but more importantly keep in mind that a Firefox OS app is basically a website so you shouldn't be thinking as an android app that can carry it's media and so on.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display images in a website you place images in the same root folder or sub folder. The same thing works with firefox OS.Place your images in your app folder and use them. If you want to use images from the mobile then you can use [device Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Storage_API) .you can find the example [here](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App)